# Why won't my time Type default to null?

Tags: mysql

If I look at my table structure under phpMyAdmin it has the following structure:

`Type - time`

`NULL - Yes`

`Default - NULL`

So why when I do a simple `INSERT INTO` ... does the value for time default to 00:00:00 even though the value I'm inputting is `null`.  I've got the same issue for type `int` but not for varchar.

EDIT - I've added the below.

zip in mysql is type int (default `NULL`), st_time in mysql is type time (default `NULL`).  I've tested the code and it works for zip but doesn't for `st_time`.

```
if($zip == NULL){
$zip = 'NULL';
}
if($st_time == NULL){
$st_time = 'NULL';
}

$cont=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(zip,st_time)VALUES($zip, $st_time)");
```

I've found this code on stackoverflow which apparently solves the problem but I don't know how to insert more than one vale using the below code.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO cb (name) VALUES (" . ($name == null ? "NULL" : "'$name'") . ")");
```

EDIT TAKE 2 with solution (warning - it's ugly)

```
if($zip == NULL){
$zip = 'NULL';
}
if($st_time == NULL){
$st_time = 'NULL';
}
else{
$st_time = "'".$st_time."'";
}

$cont=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(zip, st_time)VALUES($zip,  $st_time)");
```

Comment: Show us your table schema, and the insert statement.

Comment: Probably because your NULL is an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a quoted string `'NULL'`. 
Use `NULL` instead ( not a quoted string but the NULL value )

So set `$st_time = NULL` or rather in your case as you are testing for it being `NULL` leave it alone.

MySQL expects a `TIME` field to be passed as a string `'12:00:00'` and it can parse that into its internal storage type. If you pass a string that it cannot parse correctly it will default to `00:00:00`.

Comment: Your info helped me get to the solution.  I've update the question to show the solution.